# How to get model attributes to load LAST

Tags: jsp, spring-mvc

I have a webpage where I can create/edit/delete users.

I have code like the following:

```
@ModelAttribute("allUsers")
    public Object allUsers(){
        return someClass.getAllUsers();
    }
```

The trouble is that this is (seemingly) executed BEFORE the update/create call within the controller method.  So what seems to be happening is that the "all users" data doesn't update when a user makes a change via a POST request (or a get request, for that matter).

Other than explicitly attaching attributes to the request object in every method, is there a way to run these last?

Comment: It's kind of difficult to do as cleanly as `@ModelAttribute`. Consider using a `HandlerInterceptor` and adding the attribute to the `HttpServletRequest` attributes directly.

Comment: Attaching `@ModelAttribute` to a method that is not a handler and returns some value is a way to tell Spring MVC "Hey, if you ever seem to need one of these 'allUsers', get it from here...".  So, what is probably happening is that your handler method is also defining the same `@MA`, and thus Spring is using this to "fill it in".  That is just how it works.  Also, are you putting these in Session at all?  If so, just update the session object.  If not, plug in a Model into your handler and update it there after you get the new user.